# Extracting fields in Logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am using Logstash (with Kibana as the UI).  I would like to extract some fields from my logs so that I can filter by them on the LHS of the UI.

A sample line from my log looks like this:

```
2013-07-04 00:27:16.341 -0700 [Comp40_db40_3720_18_25] client_login=C-316fff97-5a19-44f1-9d87-003ae0e36ac9 ip_address=192.168.4.1
```

In my logstash conf file, I put this:

```
filter {
    grok {
        type => "mylog"
        pattern => "(?<CLIENT_NAME>Comp\d+_db\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)"
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to extract Comp40_db40_3720_18_25 (the number of digits can vary, but will always be at least 1 in each section separated by _) and client_login (can also be client_logout).  Then, I can search for CLIENT_NAME=Comp40... CLIENT_NAME=Comp55, etc.

Am I missing something in my config to make this a field that I can use in Kibana?

Thanks!

Comment: The regex looks good, though I would use something like (?<CLIENT_NAME>Comp[_a-z\d]+). Could you please share what is not working. By the way I am assuming you also have elasticsearch output defined in your conf file.

Comment: Yes, I am using the embedded instance of ES in Logstash.  I guess what I was expecting was that if I clicked on the @fields.client_name on the LHS (under columns), it would show me a count of all the fields it had extracted, or even a list of them, i.e. Comp40.., Comp55, etc.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess the best example of what I want would be like on the Logstash/Kibana demo (http://demo.logstash.net/).  If you click on @message, you can see a breakdown of 5 or so of the top "categories" for that type.

Answer (score 4):

If you are having any difficulty getting the  pattern to match correctly, using the [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) is a great solution.

For your given problem you could just separate out your search data into another variable, and save the additional varying digits in another (trash) variable.

For example:

```
(?<SEARCH_FIELD>Comp\d+)%{GREEDYDATA:trash_variable}]
```

(Please use the [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) on the above pattern)